# vim forgets registers (*, +) after reattaching tmux session; E353: Nothing in register

Tags: ssh, vim, tmux

I ssh into a remote system and use a vim+tmux workflow. I love it because I can detach my session at the end of the day, and when I fire it back up the next morning, it's exactly where I left off.

The problem is: when I reattach the tmux session, any open vim editor no longer recognizes the `*` or `+` registers. giving the error

`E353: Nothing in register +`

The only way I can get this to work again is if I quit out of all my vim tabs and restart it.

`vim --version` returns

```
VIM - Vi IMproved 7.4 (2013 Aug 10, compiled Nov 24 2016 16:44:48)
+clipboard
+xterm_clipboard
```

`se clipboard?` returns
`clipboard=unnamed,unnamedplus,autoselect,exclude:cons\|linux`

`:echo has('clipboard')` returns
`1`

`:echo has('xterm_clipboard')` returns
`1`

`:echo $DISPLAY` returns
`localhost:10.0` <-- this is consistant with the attached `DISPLAY`

**Is there a way to get vim to reload the `+` and `*` registres?**

Comment: There is currently some discussion on how to fix this issue https://github.com/vim/vim/issues/3649. If you can test a patch, please comment.

Answer (score 1):

It bugged me for months that sometimes I get `+`-registry  in tmux-vim and sometimes I do not. Thank you guys for populating this thread. There are two long discussions on [`vim+tmux`](https://github.com/vim/vim/issues/203) and [`vim+screen` with X11 server change](https://github.com/vim/vim/issues/3649), yet, I was not able to identify a quick fix.

For now, I use [dhruvasagar/vim-prosession](https://github.com/dhruvasagar/vim-prosession) to recover the missing `+`-registries while maintaining the previous editing session. With the default configuration, the entire session is stored upon exit when a vim session is started using `vim` from a certain directory. Now, `tmux` logs the directory, and `vim-prosession` takes care of the previous editing session.

---

#### Clipboard access over SSH (Win10)

I use a Windows 10 machine to access Tmux sessions on a Linux machine, where X410 provides clipboard support. When `+`-registry is not available, likely, the Windows clipboard is not accessible. Restarting X410 manually should fix this clipboard issue. (To my understanding, X410 is stuck somewhere, prohibiting other programs to write to Windows' clipboard.)

Separately, to get "Ctrl+C" to write to the `+`-registry in a Vim instance that is nested in a Tmux session running on the remote machine, re-attaching to the Tmux session can also break the ability to write to `+`-registry using "Ctrl+C". ==> When this happens and the Windows system clipboard is still working, the fix is to start a new pane/split in Tmux, and load a "new" Vim instance `vim-prosession`.

(Edits on 2021-11-17: added troubleshooting steps for Win10-WSL2 after the horizontal divider.)

Comment: Thanks for your answer, [dhruvasagar/vim-prosession](https://github.com/dhruvasagar/vim-prosession) solve the issue for me.

Answer (score 0):

This happens to me as well. I run `Ubuntu 16.04` VirtualBox which is my remote VM.  Everytime, I try to reconnect, I have lost the registers. I used to savestate on the VM and come to it.

These days, instead I use the `tmux-resurrect` and `tmux-continuum` extensions. These preserve the `tmux-splits`, and also the `vim`-states with `vim-obsession`. Next, instead of using savestate on the VM, I actually shut it off.

When I start it up, the registers work pretty reliably.